# Creating a table from a loop (java)

Tags: java, loops

How would I get this to print in a table? The way I have it written I can't figure out how to print all the results at the end. This is what I have :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FFLAverage{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input the number of students");
    int numofstu = input.nextInt();
    double totalchange = 0;
    for (int count = numofstu; count != 0; count--){
      if (count == numofstu)
        System.out.println("Last Name \t\t StartWeight \t\t End Weight \t\t Weight Change");
      System.out.print("Enter student name: ");
      String name = input.next();
      System.out.print("Input start weight: ");
      double start = input.nextDouble();
      System.out.print("Enter end weight: ");
      double end = input.nextDouble();
      double change = (start - end);
      totalchange += change;
      System.out.println(name + "\t\t" + start + "\t\t\t" + end + "\t\t\t" + change);
    }
    double avg = totalchange / numofstu;
    System.out.println("Average weight change: " + avg);
  }
}
```

This is what the output should look like (console)

```
Last Name Start Weight End Weight Weight Change
Noble     222.5        202.4     -23.1
Tyler     189.5        194.4      +4.9
Pond      345.1        190.0     -155.1
Average weight change: --57.33
```

Comment: Get what to print as a table? What do you consider to be the results - perhaps provide some sample output?

Comment: If you want all the names etc you need to store them into a collection rather than just single variables (which you'll lose the next time through the loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Five Step:

1. Create A Class to store the value

   static class Student {
           private String name;
           private double start;
           private double end;
           private double change;

   ```
       public String getName() {
           return name;
       }

       public void setName(String name) {
           this.name = name;
       }

       public double getStart() {
           return start;
       }

       public void setStart(double start) {
           this.start = start;
       }

       public double getEnd() {
           return end;
       }

       public void setEnd(double end) {
           this.end = end;
       }

       public double getChange() {
           return start - end;
       }

   }
   ```
2. Create the object of each input of a student.

   ```
       Student student = new Student();
   ```
3. Store the inputs for a student inside the object

   ```
           System.out.print("Enter student name[ "+(count+1) + "]: ");
           student.setName(input.next());
           System.out.print("Input start weight[ "+(count+1) + "]: ");
           student.setStart(input.nextDouble());
           System.out.print("Enter end weight[ "+(count+1)+ "]: ");
           student.setEnd(input.nextDouble());
   ```
4. Store the object in  array

   ```
    students[count] = student;
   ```
5. Iterate the array

   ```
       System.out
               .println("Last Name\t\tStartWeight\t\tEnd Weight\t\tWeight Change");
       // PARSE THE ARRAY
       for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
           System.out.println(students[i].getName() + "\t\t"
                   + students[i].getStart() + "\t\t" + students[i].getEnd()
                   + "\t\t" + students[i].getChange());
       }
   ```

Complete implementation

```
package com;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class FFLAverage {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input the number of students");
        int numofstu = input.nextInt();
        double totalchange = 0;
        Student[] students = new Student[numofstu];
        for (int count = 0; count<numofstu;count++) {
            //Put data into A CLASS
            System.out.println("--------------------------------");
            Student student = new Student();
            System.out.print("Enter student name[ "+(count+1) + "]: ");
            student.setName(input.next());
            System.out.print("Input start weight[ "+(count+1) + "]: ");
            student.setStart(input.nextDouble());
            System.out.print("Enter end weight[ "+(count+1)+ "]: ");
            student.setEnd(input.nextDouble());
            totalchange += student.getChange();
            // PUT THE OBJECT IN ARRAY
            students[count] = student;
            System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        }

        System.out
                .println("Last Name\t\tStartWeight\t\tEnd Weight\t\tWeight Change");
        // PARSE THE ARRAY
        for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(students[i].getName() + "\t\t"
                    + students[i].getStart() + "\t\t\t" + students[i].getEnd()
                    + "\t\t\t" + students[i].getChange());
        }

        double avg = totalchange / numofstu;
        System.out.println("Average weight change: " + avg);
    }

    static class Student {
        private String name;
        private double start;
        private double end;
        private double change;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public double getStart() {
            return start;
        }

        public void setStart(double start) {
            this.start = start;
        }

        public double getEnd() {
            return end;
        }

        public void setEnd(double end) {
            this.end = end;
        }

        public double getChange() {
            return start - end;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Notice the way Shastri writes the `for` loops.

Answer (score 1):

Create some sort of data container class lets call it `Student`, put aproopriate fields in it (name, weights etc.) with getters and settors or declare those fields `public`. Create `new Student`in every loop pass, and add initiaized `Student` object to a common collection like `List` lets say `LinkedList<Student> students`. After your iteration is finished, iterate over created list by eg. `for(Student s:students)` and print data you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think this exercise it to teach you about 2D arrays

You need to save your values into a 2D array

```
String[][] students = String[numofstu][4]

// inputs
// All of these inputs have to go inside a nested for loop using indexes i and j
String name = input.nextLine();
students [i][j] = name;

String beingWeight = String.valueOf(input.nextDouble());
students [i][j] = beginWeight;

String endWeight = String.valueOf(input.nextDouble());
students [i][j] = endWeight;

double wieghtChange = 
       Double.parseDouble(beginWeight)) - Double.parseDouble(endWeight));
String weightChange = String.valueOf(weightChange));
students [i][j] = weightChange;
```

When you want to print:

```
for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        // Print in your desired format
        System.out.print(students[i][j] + "     ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest for you to use a new class :

```
    class student{
        public String name ;
        public double startWeight ;
        public double endWeight
        public student(){
             name = new String() ;
        }

        public double change(){
             return (endWeight - startWeight ) ;
        }
    }
```

after that in your main class :

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class FFLAverage{
      public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input the number of students");
        int numofstu = input.nextInt();
        student[] std = new student[numofstu] ;
        double totalchange = 0;
        for (int count = numofstu; count != 0; count--){
             std[count] = new student() ;


             System.out.print("Enter student name: ");
             std[count].name = input.next();
             System.out.print("Input start weight: ");
             std[count].startWeight = input.nextDouble();
             System.out.print("Enter end weight: ");
             std[count].endWeight = input.nextDouble();
       }
       for (int count = numofstu; count != 0; count--){
            if (count == numofstu)
                 System.out.println(name + "\t\t" + start + "\t\t\t" + end + "\t\t\t" + change);
            System.out.println(std[count].name + "\t\t" + std[count].startWeight + "\t\t\t" + std[count].endWeight + "\t\t\t" + std[count].change());
            totalchange+=std[count].change() ;
       }
       double avg = totalchange / numofstu;
       System.out.println("Average weight change: " + avg);
   }
  }
```